# Zend-Framework 1.x with Doctrine 2.x

Tags: zend-framework, integration, doctrine-orm

I know that there are many examples but this is my problem, because now I don't know which is the best and I don't understand every samples. This before I used doctrine 1.x and that was more simple for me, because there was only few steps to connect to database with doctrine and use it:

1.) Created User.yml file into application/doctrine/schema folder
2.) Run generate-models-yaml in cli which generated php classes into
 application/models/generated folder
3.) Again in cli run: create-db, create-tables
4.) In IndexController / IndexAction I can use it:

```
$newUser = new User();
$newUser->name = 'Demo';
$newUser->save;
```

And that's all. But with 2.0 I have some question:
- Where is the best place for mapping yaml files?
- How can I generate Entities from yaml? (Depending from the first answer)
- How can I create/drop db and tables? 
- Which solution is the best EntitiyManager?

So I just want the most simple sample like my doctrine 1.x sample. Thanks!

Comment: This is a really broad question.  Doctrine2 is fundamentally different from Doctrine1.  I would recommend that you forget all about d1, and read/follow some doctrine2 tutorials.  Forget about yml files, and use annotations.  Once you have a handle on D2, annotations, the EntityManager, and the d2 command-line tools, then look at the various D2/ZF1 integrations.  It's incredibly important that you don't assume anything about d2 based on how things were in d1 -- they're completely different animals.

Comment: I know that there is a big difference, but both db manager so I think the D2 need to know the default database functions. Or I need create a database from command line? And in the cli I can use orm:generate-entities (from mapping file) but I didn't find the mapping place. And after that can I create tables from cli? So my problem that I don't se how can I build my database by doctrine2

Answer (score 2):

For me best integration Bisna from     Guilherme Blanco https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2

Step by step video tutorial using Bisna integration 
http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/

Comment: Please be aware that the code talked about in the video was for Doctrine 2.0. Doctrine 2.1 and 2.2 are not compatible anymore with that version of Bisna. It's best to pick the latest Bisna version and to look to another skeleton application how it's implemented. For example: https://github.com/keesschepers/SolrExample is integrated with Doctrine 2.2 and Bisna.

Answer (score 1):

Another very good example of ZF1 and Doctrine 2 with fully tested code (PHPUnit & Ant):

https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD-

They try to work best practice. Always.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents, I've wrote a [Zend Framework 1.x resource](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/#bgylib-components-bgy-application-resource-doctrine2) for Doctrine 2.0

The source code is available on [github](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary).

Answer (score 0):

This is another sample about zf1 and D2
https://github.com/marsbomber/zf1-doctrine2/tree/modular_setup

I used it and I think it was useful.